Error: Function not defined for given argument type(s) when defining Kalman Filter block in Scilab

Body:
I am working on a project involving a Kalman Filter block in Scilab. While executing my code, I encountered an error regarding argument types. The error message is as follows:
Function not defined for given argument type(s),
  check arguments or define function %l_e for overloading.

Details of the execution:
I ran the following commands:
exec('C:\Users\Vimal\Desktop\spacecraft-gnc-tbx-devel-kalman-filter-block\macros\System_IF.sci', -1);
exec('C:\Users\Vimal\Desktop\spacecraft-gnc-tbx-devel-kalman-filter-block\builder.sce', -1);

The build process starts fine, but during the Kalman Filter block definition, the error is thrown. Here is part of the output leading up to the error:
"Model structure before standard_define:"
...
at line 167 of function System_IF ( C:\Users\Vimal\Desktop\spacecraft-gnc-tbx-devel-kalman-filter-block\macros\System_IF.sci line 167 )
at line 1 of executed string 
at line 78 of function tbx_build_blocks ( C:\Program Files\scilab-2024.0.0\modules\modules_manager\macros\tbx_build_blocks.sci line 90 )
...

Key details:

The error occurs at line 167 of System_IF.sci.
The function seems to be related to defining a Kalman Filter block, but it’s not clear what is wrong with the argument types.
The matrices involved (A, B, C, D, etc.) are defined, but the program fails at block definition.

My question:

What could be causing the "Function not defined for given argument type(s)" error in this context?
How can I resolve or debug this issue related to argument types in Scilab when defining a system model?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I tried executing the script files to build the Kalman Filter block and expected the block to be defined successfully without errors. I expected the system model to be created with the specified matrices and parameters (A, B, C, D matrices, and initial state).
However, instead of the model being built, I received an error about the function not being defined for the given argument types, which caused the build process to stop. I'm unsure which argument is causing this issue or how to resolve it.

I saw this and your previous question. Stackoverflow can occasionally help with this kind of thing, but I've found that it's often not worth the time to type everything up and provide enough context that people here can answer your question. FWIW, I would suggest spending more time googling around and testing different things rather than writing questions to SO. The error message mentions the %l_e function; have you looked into that? Is there an example on the scilab website that you can get to work and then add complexity from there?

This is not function made by me. It's system generated function. I already posted in Scilab but not worth it.
